# iOS Inputs in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I have followed [this](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/02/12/custom-uitableviewcell-text-input-swift/) tutorial for building a text field form inside a table and i've managed to do it but in the tutorial he just uses a single type for the fields. I want some fields to have dropdowns and i'll also add other fields.

I'm not sure of the best way to do this, i'm guessing the fields need to be in an array to make it a lot easier to manage. I was thinking of the code below, the structs are just generic for now.

```
struct DropdownInput {
    let name: String
    let placeholder: String
    let defaultValue: String
    let values: [String]
}

struct TextInput {
    let name: String
    let placeholder: String
    let defaultValue: String
}

var formFields: [Any] = [
    TextInput(name: "test1", placeholder: "Some value", defaultValue: ""),
    DropdownInput(name: "test2", placeholder: "Some value", defaultValue: "", values: ["Test1","TEST2","Test3"]),
]
```

Edit: My code is working but I think it's not unpacking the formField object properly. It's saying value of type Any has no member name, how can I access the values?

```
    if self.formFields[indexPath.row] is TextInput {
        if let fieldValues: Any = self.formFields[indexPath.row] as? TextInput {
            if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellTextField") as? TextInputTableViewCell {
                print(fieldValues.name)
                return cell
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which error did you get? Also you can reduce code by using `if let textInput = formFields[index] as? TextInput`

Comment: make sure you have attached TextInputTableViewCell class for both cells.

Comment: and I'd suggest to use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath` so that you'll be sure you registered cell's class/nib

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question that "any has no member name" - just remove Any and use

```
if let fieldValues = formFields[indexPath.row] as? TextInput {
   print(fieldValues.name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a little simple if you have two different cells;

```
struct TextInput {
    let cellIdentifier: String    
    let name: String
    let placeholder: String
    let defaultValue: String
    let values: [String]
}

var formFields: [TextInput] = [
    TextInput(cellIdentifier: "cellTextField", name: "test1", placeholder: "Some value", defaultValue: "", values: []),
    TextInput(cellIdentifier: "cellDropdownTextField", name: "test2", placeholder: "Some value", defaultValue: "", values: ["Test1","TEST2","Test3"]),
]
```

and then;

```
let txtInput:TextInput = self.formFields[indexPath.row]; //It is not optional, so no if condition.
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(txtInput.cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell; //It must return cell, if the cell is registered so no if condition here too.

return cell;
```